# K8s fails to assign floating ip to loadbalancer with octavia

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I have

- an openstack, it is Queens, it has octavia for lbaas
- a small (test) k8s cluster on top of it (3 nodes, 1 master), version 9.1.2
- a deployment called `hello` which serves a simple webpage saying 'hello world', it works when accessed from within the cluster

I want to expose my deployment as a load balanced service with a floating IP.

I did `kubectl expose deployment hello --type=LoadBalancer --name=my-service`

It says (`kubectl describe service my-service`)

`Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service default/my-service: error getting floating ip for port 9cc6442b-2b2f-4b6a-8f91-65dbc2ff13d0: Resource not found`

If I manually do: `openstack floating ip --port 9cc6442b-2b2f-4b6a-8f91-65dbc2ff13d0 356c8ffa-7bc2-43a9-a8d3-29147ae01727`
where:

```
| ID                                   | Floating IP Address | Port                                 | Floating Network                     |
| 356c8ffa-7bc2-43a9-a8d3-29147ae01727 | 172.27.81.241       | None                                 | eb31cc74-96ba-4394-aef4-0e94bec46d85 |
```

and  /etc/kubernetes/cloud_config has:

```
[LoadBalancer]
subnet-id=6a6cdc35-8dda-4982-850e-53c6ee5a5085
floating-network-id=eb31cc74-96ba-4394-aef4-0e94bec46d85
use-octavia=True
```

(so it is looking for floating IPs on the correct network, and that subnet is the k8s internal subnet)

It all works.

So everything except "associate an IP" has worked.  Why does this step fail? Where has k8s logged what it did and how it failed?  I can only find docs for pod level logging (and my pod is fine, and serving it's test webpage just great).

(I have lots of quota remaining for 'make more floating ips', and several unused ones hanging around)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this [No Ports Available when trying to associate a floating IP](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/54713/no-ports-available-when-trying-to-associate-a-floating-ip/) and this [Failed to Associate Floating IP](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/111490/failed-to-associate-floating-ip/). Maybe those will point you into right direction.

I would recommend that you check this page [OpenStack community](https://ask.openstack.org/) and look for more answers as I'm not an expert in OpenStack.

As for your question

> Where has k8s logged what it did and how it failed?

You can use `kubectl describe service <service_name>`

> Show details of a specific resource or group of resources
>
> Print a detailed description of the selected resources, including related resources such as events or controllers. You may select a single object by name, all objects of that type, provide a name prefix, or label selector. For example:
>
> `$ kubectl describe TYPE NAME_PREFIX`

For mode debug description please check [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/).